# Como eliminar un objeto de una colección por su _id en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Tengo el siguiente documento:

```
Nro_Orden: '100',
Tipo: 'Solicitud de market',
Estado: 'Orden en espera',
time: 2020-07-12T19:59:18.980Z,
Lista:
    [ { _id: 5f0b6ba0d9cea95868dbea56,
        Codf: '7750182001687',
        Descr: 'Coca Cola 2.5l',
        Catd: 12 },
        { _id: 5f0b6bafd9cea95868dbea57,
        Codf: '7751580000968',
        Descr: 'Pepsi 3l',
        Catd: 6 } ],
__v: 0 }
```

Mi objetivo es enviar el id de cualquier objeto dentro del array 'Lista' al backend y luego eliminarlo usando `findByIdAndDelete`; tal que así:

**ENVIO EL ID AL BACKEND**

```
const delItem = async (id) => {
    const res = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/api/ordenes/${id}`);
    console.log(res)
}
```

**RECIBO EL ID Y TRATO DE ELIMINARLO** (aquí mi problema)

```
ordenCtrl.delItem = async (req, res) => {
    const id_delete = req.params.id;
    const lol = await ordenesExtremas.findByIdAndDelete({Lista: id_delete});
    console.log(lol)
}
```

No se cual es la sintaxis correcta para eliminar un objeto dentro de un array, cabe resaltar que uso `mongdb` y `express`.

También adjunto el error que me sale:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ Lista: '5f0ba93fc7168922a4f833f0' }" at path "_id" for model "ordenesXprocesar"

Comment: Lo primero a tener en cuenta es saber si estamos modificando el documento correcto. Tu modelo `ordenesExtremas` apunta a una colección que puede tener muchos documentos que contengan en su campo *Lista* el elemento que deseas eliminar. Para realmente modificar el documento adecuado necesitas el `id` de la *ordenExtrema* que deseas modificar (supongo que es distinto que el `id` que hay dentro del campo *Lista*). ¿Podrías aclarar ese detalle? Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Editado: aclaración de endpoint REST a partir del comentario de @MauricioContreras

El método `findByIdAndDelete` te sirve para hacer una consulta por `_id` del objeto padre. O sea es como hacer un `findOneAndDelete({_id: <id>})` [link a la documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete).

Por otro lado, este método lo que va a hacer es borrarte el documento completo. Entiendo que lo que necesitas es hacer un `pull()` [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) para borrar ese elemento del array, entonces lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
ordenCtrl.delItem = async (req, res) => {
    const id_delete = req.params.idElemento;
    const nroOrden = req.params.nroOrden;
    try {
        const lol = await ordenesExtremas.updateOne({Nro_Orden: nroOrden}, {$pull: {Lista: {_id: id_delete}}});
        console.log(lol)
    }
    catch (e) {
        // Manejar el error
    }
}
```

Dejo una aclaración con respecto al endpoint que estás utilizando para hacer el DELETE, respetando REST. El mismo debería ser de la siguiente forma:

`DELETE /api/ordenes/<nroOrden>/listas/<idElemento>`

- `<nroOrden>`: Debe ir este parámetro para poder identificar unívocamente la orden a editar (en este caso estamos eliminando un elemento de la lista).
- `<idElemento>`: Es el id con el que vas a buscar en el array `Lista`.
- Respetar la jerarquización natural: justamente con esto estamos poniendo atención al comentario de @MarioContreras. Ya que, el endpoint que está arriba se lee de la siguiente manera: "Borrá el elemento con id `<idElemento>` de la orden con el número `<nroOrden>`". Conclusión: Nos permite saber qué documento editar.

Comment: Tu implementación, aunque en cierta forma es correcta, tiene un defecto. `findOne` en cualquiera de sus formas `update` o `delete`, tomará el primer elemento de la colección que coincida con el filtro. Si dos o más documentos contienen en su lista el producto con el `id` especificado ¿Cómo saber si estamos modificando el documento correcto? Saludos

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en lo que mencionas. Por lo tanto, agregaría además de esto lo siguiente:
- Como está utilizando REST el endpoint debería ser `DELETE /api/ordenes/<nro de orden>/lista/<id>`.

Edito mi respuesta con lo mencionado